# How to set different setInterval speed using fullpage.js

Tags: setinterval, fullpage.js

I have different sections as per below:

```
<div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section" id="first" data-sec="1000">First</div>
 <div class="section" id="second" data-sec="3000">Second</div>
 <div class="section" id="third" data-sec="6000">Third</div>
 <div class="section" id="fourth" data-sec="1000">Fourth</div>
```

My current code for fullpage.js as below:

```
var curDelay = 1000;
$("#fullpage").fullpage({
    loopBottom: true,
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        var curDelay = $(this).data('sec');
        console.log(curDelay);
    },
});

setInterval(goSection,curDelay);

function goSection() {
$.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
}
```

I want to set different setInterval speed based on each data-sec value. Currently it just use the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the interval and create it again in `afterLoad`.

Try this:

```
var curDelay = 1000;
var intervalID;
$("#fullpage").fullpage({
    loopBottom: true,
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        var curDelay = $(this).data('sec');
        clearInterval(intervalID); // <-- here
        intervalID = setInterval(goSection, curDelay); // <-- here
    },

    afterRender: function(){
        intervalID = setInterval(goSection, curDelay); // <-- here
    } 
});


function goSection() {
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have to remove this line:

afterRender: function(){
        intervalID = setInterval(goSection, curDelay); // <-- here
    }

to make it work

Comment: I don't see why you would have to remove it. That should be the proper way of doing it, as the afterRender callbacks assures you the timeout will only be called whenever fullPage.js structure is ready.

Comment: In any case, please accept the answer if it was useful for you, so others with the same question can find it useful.